# Same named variables but in different if statements?

Tags: php

Is this bad practice?

```
if($_POST['formvalue'] == '1') {
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username) VALUES ('$username')";
mysql_query($sql);}

elseif($_POST['formvalue'] != '1') {
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (email) VALUES ('$email')";
mysql_query($sql);}
```

Notice how I have used the same name variable? Does it matter and is it bad practice when dealing with elseif statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't matter. But I would ask is that `$sql` variable necessary, why not put the string literal into the call to `mysql_query()` instead of using the `$sql` variable.

eg:

```
if($_POST['formvalue'] == '1') {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts (username) VALUES ('$username')");
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts (email) VALUES ('$email')");
}
```

It removes the need for the `$sql` variable entirely. Also you don't need that extra `if` on the `else if` as you are testing the opposite of the first if.

Comment: How do you mean? I am new to this sort of thing and I still am learning, if it is better practice then I will indeed do it :) And thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I actually like this

```
if($_POST['formvalue'] == '1') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username) VALUES ('$username')";
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (email) VALUES ('$email')";
}
mysql_query($sql);
```